# How can I Customise reach big calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

How do I change the background cell color for a particular date in react big calendar. is there any custom way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

You can set eventPropGetter function, which takes event from cell and returns object with proper style, for example:

```
<Calendar
    eventPropGetter={event => ({
        style: {
            backgroundColor: event.start.getDay() < 5
                ? "#ad4ca4"
                : "#3174ad",
        }
    })}
/>
```